# Developing a Python Flask app on localhost gets cached + Chrome/Mozilla

Tags: python, caching

That's probably a very trivial problem:

I'm following the Flask Mega Tutorial until I run into the following an issue. I wasted a good amount of time until I remembered that browsers cache pages. That's at least what I think that the problem is.

The browser just gives me the first version that I have executed.

Or perhaps it's not just the browser because I just used "clear cache and hard reload".

**Edit:**

Here is some more info. This is what I had initially:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello World of Flasks!</h>"

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(debug=True)
```

Then I did this:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return "<h1>Hello World of Flask!</h>"

@app.route("/user/<name>")
def user(name):
    return "<h1>Hello, %s!</h1>" % name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But I still get "Hello World of Flasks!" and nothing else works! (Please note I've changed |"Flasks" to "Flask" whenever I run the app. I use PyCharm CE if that matters.

Comment: Does restarting Flask work? What OS are you running this on?

Comment: Sorry: I use Windows 7. I closed PyCharm, all consoles. When I reload the page the browser tells me that it cannot find the page. Then I start PyCharm, run the app and I get the same result. Do you mean that the server might run in the background somehow?

Comment: I do this: localhost:5000 - OK, localhost:5000/index - page not found, localhost:5000/user/sfdfs - page not found and the same is if I use 127.0.0.1:5000 etc.

Comment: If you are running the server and still see the old page, you apparently are still running the old code, not the new. Either you are not changing the correct file, or Python thinks the file has not been changed and is running stale bytecode.

Comment: That might be it and I have a really bad and shameful feeling here :) BTW. I don't see any compiled bytecode in the folder.

Comment: `.pyc` files might be hidden; for the main script no bytecode file is written however. In this case I'd not expect to find one.

Comment: You were right! I setup PyCharm to run the incorrect script! Very shameful indeed!